# VLC on Ubuntu won't resize window to video

Tags: vlc

VLC on Mac and Windows works beautifully. Press Alt/Ctrl/Command+1/2/3/4, and you get a bigger or smaller **WINDOW**, perfectly containing the video.

In Ubuntu, you **resize** (not **zoom**, as VLC wrongly calls it), the window remains huge with black space filling the whole screen.

I have played with "Resize interface to video size" which resizes neither the window, nor the interface when checked, as well as Prefs > Video > Window Properties > Video Auto Scaling. No dice.

Desired behavior, and what happens on VLC on Mac and Windows: window always resizes to the video, and video always resizes the window. This is intuitive, and should be the default. For example, once you're dragging a corner of a window around to resize it, the video inside  scales. Why it doesn't scale when you Ctrl+1 it to tiny, but does scale when you drag it manually down to same tiny dimensions makes no sense. I'm not sure it's even possible to get this behavior on Ubuntu.

Also, window and video size("zoom") should both persist when looping. This happens in Windows/Mac, but not Ubuntu, where it's as if it's opening the video for the first time when it loops, making it huge or tiny. One video, it will always do this resizing every few seconds.

Comment: It works fine here (Ubuntu 16.04) with VLC from Ubuntu repos (vlc 2.2.2-5). Which version of Ubuntu / vlc are you using? Do you have external ppas enabled on your system?

Comment: The latest for 16.10, and yes, I have ppas, but not for VLC.

Comment: Maybe is another ppa that interferes with it. Try from a live system and see how it goes. But before that, you might want to try with a different user, just to be sure that the problem is not on your user.

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>2</kbd>/<kbd>3</kbd>/<kbd>4</kbd> is working just fine on my system. I am using Ubuntu 16.10.
Try reinstalling it. In the terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get remove vlc

sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Alternatively, so the same using Ubuntu Software Center.